# Postgresql 11 How can I reorder the physical rows in the database according to a timestamp

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I have a table called streams which has several rows, I like to change the order of the physical rows in the database according to the created_on column . I have a total of 179 rows, row (id) 179 is supposed to have the latest created_on date, then row (id) 178 should have the second newest created_on date . As you can see from the small snippet below things are not in order for example the date on id 172 is newer than the one on id 179 . I could get the correct data by doing this

```
 select * from streams order by created_on desc
```

however they want it to search by id such as this

```
select * from streams order by id desc
```

The following query above produced the results below . We had everything working correctly but we did a migration from Postgres 10 to Postgres 11 and messed up on the order of things.

[image]

Comment: Your audience wants to see highest ID first or latest created ID first?

Comment: The highest ID will also have the latest created ID first going forward . However the issue is that we migrated those 179 records and they got inserted in random order . I am now trying to correct that by updating the ID’s of those 179 records according to latest created on date . I just can’t seem to find a way to do that .

Comment: There is no such thing as "the order of the rows". Rows in a relational database have not "order" whatsoever. The **only** (really: the _only_) way to guarantee an order is to use an `order by` when you _select_ the rows. If you if you change the physical order somehow, there is no guarantee whatsoever that a query will return them in that order. The **only** way to guarantee an order is to use an `order by` there is no alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can re-generate the `id` column values with an `UPDATE` such as the following:

```sql
UPDATE streams SET id = tmp.row_id
FROM  (SELECT id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY created_on, id) AS row_id FROM streams) AS tmp
WHERE streams.id = tmp.id;
```

After that, you might want to re-order the rows physically on disk using [`CLUSTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-cluster.html):

```sql
CLUSTER streams USING <index-for-id-column>;
```